# Reevaluate command CanExecute on child model property change

Tags: catel

Currently we have the following models:

```
public class Model : ModelBase
{
    public Model()
    {
        ChildModel = new ChildModel();
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(FirstNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData FirstNameProperty = RegisterProperty("FirstName", typeof(string), string.Empty);

    public ChildModel ChildModel
    {
        get { return GetValue<ChildModel>(ChildModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ChildModelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyData ChildModelProperty = RegisterProperty("ChildModel", typeof(ChildModel), null);
}

public class ChildModel : ModelBase
{
    public static readonly PropertyData TestStringProperty = RegisterProperty("TestString", typeof(string), null);

    public string TestString
    {
        get { return GetValue<string>(TestStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestStringProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

We use a Model in our ViewModel

```
[Model]
public Model AModel
{
    get { return GetValue<Model>(AModelProperty); }
    private set { SetValue(AModelProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly PropertyData AModelProperty = RegisterProperty("Prescription", typeof(Model));
```

There is a command in our ViewModel with a CanExecute function.
I'd like the CanExecute to reevaluate any time a property in the Model or in the ChildModel changes.

Is there an easy way to do this?

(Note that our actual production model has multiple child models and lists that contain other ModelBases)

Currently i'm doing it by hooking into all the PropertyChanged events on all the child models, but this seems like a dirty way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to write your own "watching mechanism". You can use the `ChangeNotificationWrapper` in Catel for this.

Whenever a child model updates, you can call `ViewModelCommandManager.InvalidateCommands(true)`.